# How can I get the Latex compilation report by using AUCTeX in spacemacs

Tags: latex, auctex, spacemacs

How can I get the compilation report by using AUCTeX in spacemacs? 
For example, when I use WinEdt in Windows, i can obtain the following compilation report:

**LaTeX Compilation Report (Pages:14)

Error:0 Warnings: 32 Bad Box: 19**

Can anyone tell me how to achieve such info. in spacemacs with AUTeX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to catch warnings and bad boxes, set `TeX-debug-warnings` and `TeX-debug-bad-boxes` variables to `t`.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Is it possible to get the total number of errors/warnings/bad boxes? WinEdt provides this function and it is useful for me. Normally, i need to know whether or not the numbers are changed, because some of them are difficult to figure out, but i  want to check the increasing number.

Comment: No, it seems it was never requested as feature.  It's possible to do but one needs to redefine an internal function of AUCTeX.  I hope I'll find some time to implement this feature later this month.

Comment: Thanks Giordano. Look forward to your contribution. I think  regular-expressions can be used to analyse the compilation result line by line, which contains some key words, like warning or overfull, to calculate the total number of warnings or bad boxes. For errors, the process can be terminated. Does it make sense?

Comment: All information are present in `TeX-error-list` variable (provided that `TeX-parse-all-errors` is set to `t`, which is the default).  One just needs to count each type (or even do so while parsing the output log buffer).